# Powershell Add Member/Column Based on Another Column

Tags: python, powershell, api

I have a script that I wrote in Python that I'm trying to replicate with Powershell, which I only started using for the first time yesterday.

It gets data from an API, transforms the data a bit, and then puts it to a SQL server database.

With Python, I get the json that is returned from the POST request and put it into a dataframe. The data includes a reading_id, date_recorded, and the measurement. The date in date_recorded is just a string, but it is in UTC. I created a new column in my dataframe named date_recorded_pst with the date in date_recorded converted to PST.

To do this I created a convertToPst function and then used df.apply like below (this probably isn't the best way to do it but it works)

```
def convertToPST(utcString):
    format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
    dt_utc = datetime.strptime(utcString, format)
    dt_utc = dt_utc.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
    
    dt_pst = dt_utc.astimezone(tz = pst)
    pst_str = dt_pst.strftime(format)
    
    return pst_str

df['date_recorded_pst'] = df['date_recorded'].apply(lambda x : convertToPST(x))
```

How can I do the same in Powershell? Sorry I'm not caught up to speed on PS lingo. Is adding this new column the same as adding a new "Member"?

This is what I have so far:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod @Parameters 

$readings = $response.readings

$readings2 = $readings | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty qa
```

The last line was because I wanted to remove a column called qa. I just found it in another thread. Is there a better way to do that?

Here are the last two readings in $readings2

```
reading_id       : 500000023713225
date_recorded    : 2023-02-09T02:43:00
systolic_mmhg    : 112
diastolic_mmhg   : 73


reading_id       : 500000023671605
date_recorded    : 2023-02-08T15:52:00
systolic_mmhg    : 112
diastolic_mmhg   : 73
```

What I want:

```
reading_id       : 500000023713225
date_recorded    : 2023-02-09T02:43:00
systolic_mmhg    : 112
diastolic_mmhg   : 73
date_recorded_pst: 2023-02-08T18:43:00


reading_id       : 500000023671605
date_recorded    : 2023-02-08T15:52:00
systolic_mmhg    : 112
diastolic_mmhg   : 73
date_recorded_pst: 2023-02-08T07:52:00
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Select-Object` is one of the available options tho what it does is actually create new objects based on the arguments passed to the cmdlet. `PSObject.Properties.Remove('propertyName')` is another option, this one actually updates the object by removing the property (not all instances allow this tho). On the other hand, your question if I understand correctly is how you can have a new column from this output that converts the UTC date to PST right?

Comment: @santiagosquarzon yep! I'd like to have a new "column" that has the UTC date converted to PST. but I'd like to keep the original UTC date column as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=net-7.0) to convert a [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0) to a specific Time Zone. The method has 2 overloads of interest, both would work in this case but also one of them will require you to convert these string date times into a `datetime` instance and then call [`ToLocalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=net-7.0) assuming your Time Zone is not UTC. Both examples below using one of the dates in your question:

```bash
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
    ([datetime] '2023-02-09T02:43:00').ToLocalTime(),
    'Pacific Standard Time'
).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss') # => 2023-02-08T18:43:00

[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
    '2023-02-09T02:43:00',        # the method implicitly casts `datetime` to this string
    'UTC',                        # from TimeZone
    'Pacific Standard Time'       # to TimeZone
).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss') # => 2023-02-08T18:43:00
```

Knowing this and since you're already using [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2), we can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3) to create the new objects adding this *new calculated property*:

```bash
Invoke-RestMethod @Parameters |
    ForEach-Object readings |
    Select-Object *, @{
        N = 'date_recorded_pst'
        E = {
            [TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
                $_.date_recorded,
                'UTC',
                'Pacific Standard Time'
            ).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')
        }
    } -ExcludeProperty qa
```